# Cesium JS How to fade a polyline to transparent

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I had a look at Material Fade, but it was not working well and I had to try to find the direction of the polyline. Not sure if Fade even works with polyline with 20 points...

Is there a better way to change the color between each polyline point?

Or a working example of using Material Fade is much appreciated!

The PerInstanceColorAppearance sounds like what I'm looking for... but I have no idea how to implement this for the Polyline in the PolylineCollection...

---

How does a polyline collection with several polylines that is added to the primitives translate into something like this from the example http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Geometry%20and%20Appearances.html

```
    positions = [];
    colors = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
        positions.push(ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(-100.0 + i, 9.0)));
        colors.push(Cesium.Color.fromRandom({alpha : 1.0}));
    }

    primitives.add(new Cesium.Primitive({
        geometryInstances : new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
            geometry : new Cesium.PolylineGeometry({
                positions : positions,
                width : 10.0,
                vertexFormat : Cesium.PolylineColorAppearance.VERTEX_FORMAT,
                colors : colors,
                colorsPerVertex : true
            })
        }),
        appearance : new Cesium.PolylineColorAppearance()
    }));
```

I've also added a life-duration attribute to each polyline to determine when they need to be removed from the polyline collection. Potentially I have a lot of polylines that need to be added and removed per second and each polyline has different points.